# I derived a formula for SIP calculations myself, but I'm unsure if it's accurate. Could you please help me verify it?

Tags: finance

[This is the formula I derived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJssp.jpg)

Here, for simplicity, P is the amount you invest every year, T is the total number of years you invest your money, and R is the Interest Rate for every year. Please someone verify this formula and suggest some modifications to this formula if required.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to type your formula. Provide some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), why is it formula interesting and important?